# AWS Lambda "Process exited before completing request" when adding dependency

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, system.drawing

I am attempting to upload a function in AWS Lambda which carries out some image processing functions.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 along with the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio to develop and upload the function to AWS Lambda. AWS Lambda is using the .Net Core 2.1 (C#/PowerShell) runtime with the Handler set to the FunctionHandler function.

My function that I am attempting to upload to AWS Lambda is as follows:

```
using System;

using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

using Amazon.Lambda.Core;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace LambdaTest
{
public class Function
{
    public object FunctionHandler(MapsAPI input)
    {
        try
        {
            // Form the request for each tile
            Uri uri = new Uri(input.GetFullUri(), UriKind.Absolute);

            Bitmap bitOutput = null;
            string contentType = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
                using (WebResponse response = req.GetResponse())
                {
                    // Save content type to use later when passing bitmap on to webpage
                    contentType = response.ContentType;

                    // The response stream is the map tile image to display
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        bitOutput = new Bitmap(stream);

                        // We will apply a watermark for higher zoom levels
                        // coresponding to VML and MM Topo
                        if (Convert.ToDouble(input.z) >= 9.0)
                        {
                            // Create a Graphics object from the bitmap instance
                            using (Graphics gphx = Graphics.FromImage(bitOutput))
                            {
                                // Create a font
                                Font fontWatermark = new Font("Verdana", 16, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                                // Indicate that the text should be centered
                                StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat()
                                {
                                    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                                    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                                };

                                // Add the watermark...
                                gphx.DrawString(
                                    "Mapping",
                                    fontWatermark,
                                    new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Navy)),
                                    new Rectangle(10, 10, bitOutput.Width - 10, bitOutput.Height - 10),
                                    stringFormat);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.Message;
                string msg2 = ex.InnerException.Message;
                if (bitOutput != null) { bitOutput.Dispose(); }
                TileStream output = new TileStream
                {
                    contentType = msg + " : " + msg2
                };
                return output;
            }

            ImageFormat format;
            switch (contentType)
            {
                case "image/png":
                    format = ImageFormat.Png;
                    break;
                case "image/gif":
                    format = ImageFormat.Gif;
                    break;
                default:
                    format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                    break;
            }

            if (bitOutput != null)
            {
                TileStream output = new TileStream
                { contentType = contentType };

                bitOutput.Save(output.imageStream, format);
                bitOutput.Dispose();
                return output;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { return null; }
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, the code makes use of System.Drawing. I became aware the AWS Lambda does not implement the System.Drawing class and thus I have to use a substitue to carry out the drawing functionality.

I initially installed the System.Drawing.Common NuGet package, however when I tried to run the Lambda function it returned with the Exception Error:

> '"The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception. : Unable to load
>   shared library 'libdl' or one of its dependencies.'

After looking online, one of the solutions recommended trying the CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2 instead for my drawing tools.

I installed this package and was met with a different exception:

> The type initializer for 'System.Drawing.GDIPlus' threw an exception.
>   : Unable to load shared library 'gdiplus' or one of its dependencies

Solutions online told me that I needed to download the Linux Runtime for this package in order for it to successfully execute, and thus I downloaded the runtime.linux-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing package from NuGet.

After installing the package and updating AWS Lambda, I am now receiving the following error:

> {"errorMessage":"RequestId: ded846b8-a3e2-4f24-90fb-ef0e9a688ba8
>   Process exited before completing request"}

which suggests that the code now is not even running.

Any solutions on why installing the runtime.linux package seems to prevent the code from compiling/running on AWS Lambda, or perhaps any other NuGet packages that I could try for my System.Drawing functions would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Edit:
Here is a CloudWatch log for my function whenever the error is generated:

```
09:55:06
START RequestId: abeab72f-b522-4d2b-b839-939c648d8f02 Version: $LATEST
09:55:08
END RequestId: abeab72f-b522-4d2b-b839-939c648d8f02
09:55:08
REPORT RequestId: abeab72f-b522-4d2b-b839-939c648d8f02  Duration: 2065.84 ms    Billed Duration: 2100 ms Memory Size: 512 MB    Max Memory Used: 120 MB
09:55:08
RequestId: abeab72f-b522-4d2b-b839-939c648d8f02 Process exited before completing request
```

Comment: increase timeout?

Comment: I've already tried increasing this to 60 seconds but to no avail. If I perform a test on Visual Studio and Localhost using the Mock Lambda Test Tool the code executes successfully. I have added the Cloud Watch logs to my original question as well to help further.